Error dequeuing custom UICollectionViewCell
Using Xcode 16 beta, I'm now getting the following runtime error.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected dequeued view to be returned to the collection view in preparation for display. When the collection view's data source is asked to provide a view for a given index path, ensure that a single view is dequeued and returned to the collection view. Avoid dequeuing views without a request from the collection view. For retrieving an existing view in the collection view, use -[UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:] or -[UICollectionView supplementaryViewForElementKind:atIndexPath:]. 
It gets thrown on my
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate

which is making it difficult to locate the actual offending code.
The error message does say that the Dequeued View is a custom class that extends UICollectionViewCell:
Dequeued view: <MyProject.MyCollectionViewCell: 0x15393d780; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell;
At this point, I'd like to be able to figure out where the actual dequeue is that's causing this?  Or is it possible its not in the dequeue?
Full Stack Trace
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Expected dequeued view to be returned to the collection view in preparation for display. When the collection view's data source is asked to provide a view for a given index path, ensure that a single view is dequeued and returned to the collection view. Avoid dequeuing views without a request from the collection view. For retrieving an existing view in the collection view, use -[UICollectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:] or -[UICollectionView supplementaryViewForElementKind:atIndexPath:]. Dequeued view: <MyProject.MyCollectionViewCell: 0x15393d780; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (34 35; 325 90); opaque = NO; backgroundColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000045af9a0>>; Collection view: <UICollectionView: 0x11ddf1e00; frame = (0 0; 393 582.333); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000de1920>; backgroundColor = <UIDynamicCatalogColor: 0x60000219acb0; name = sptBackground>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000007510a0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {393, 159}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x1042a4c70>; dataSource: <MyProject.MyCollectionsViewController: 0x11dde5200>>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804b70ec __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018008ede8 objc_exception_throw + 72
    2   Foundation                          0x0000000180e73aa8 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x00000001851ace44 __43-[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:]_block_invoke.444 + 136
    4   UIKitCore                           0x0000000185a9811c -[_UICollectionViewSubviewManager removeAllDequeuedViewsWithEnumerator:] + 188
    5   UIKitCore                           0x00000001851ac90c -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4000
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00000001851b1714 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 284
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000186016438 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2404
    8   QuartzCore                          0x000000018b059eb0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 432
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000018600583c -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 308
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000018529304c -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 812
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000018528cac4 -[UINavigationController _layoutTopViewControllerLookForNested:] + 416
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000018528b004 -[UINavigationController _didEndTransitionFromView:toView:wasCustom:] + 820
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185c31908 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionConductor _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 1004
    14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185c311b0 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionConductor startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 640
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185293d4c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 80
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000018527bb00 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 168
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000186016438 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2404
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000018b059eb0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 432
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000018b064c34 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 124
    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000018af99c58 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 464
    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000018afc8468 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 652
    22  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185ab8260 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 32
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041b0ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018041a824 

__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 352
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001804150c8 __CFRunLoopRun + 812
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000180414960 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 536
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x000000019016fb10 GSEventRunModal + 160
    28  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185a9f650 -[UIApplication _run] + 796
    29  UIKitCore                           0x0000000185aa3848 UIApplicationMain + 124
    30  MyProject.debug.dylib          0x000000010983da34 __debug_main_executable_dylib_entry_point + 64
    31  dyld                                0x000000010298d410 start_sim + 20
    32  ???                                 0x0000000102b92154 0x0 + 4340654420
    33  ???                                 0x352f000000000000 0x0 + 3832281807915581440
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

UPDATE
I have narrowed down the issue to this block of code in cellForItemAt:

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:item.reuseIdentifier(), for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

 switch cell {
 case is CollectionViewCell:

if let customCell = cell as? CustomCollectionViewCell {
    
    if Device.isPhone && (item is FirstTypeItem || item is SecondTypeItem) {
        
        guard let phoneCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "PhoneCell", for: indexPath) as? PhoneCollectionCell else {
            return cell // Return the original cell if casting fails
        }
        
        phoneCell.setSomeValue(value)
        return phoneCell
    }
    
    customCell.setSomeValue(otherValue)
    return customCell
}

return cell

Once the dequeuReusableCell is called with the "PhoneCell" reuse identifier, I run into the above error.
The "PhoneCell" reuse identifier is not registered.  If I register it, then I do not hit the above error, but instead I get nil @IBOutlet's in the didSet of the PhoneCollectionType cell.
collectionView.register(PhoneCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PHoneCell")
I think it has to do with dequeuing from the same indexPath twice, with a different reuseIdentifier the second time

Set an exception breakpoint.  Also, [edit] your question to show your relevant collection view delegate methods

Share the full stacktrace when it crashes + related methods cellForItem, etc.

Please share your cellForRowAtIndexPath(:) code.
Or else look into your code if you use any guard or if conditions and return an empty collection view cell return UICollectionViewCell() ? look into your if/guard condition why it is failing.

I have added code from the cellForItemAt

Basically, if you declare a dequeueReusableCell you must return that that cell. Since you're returning the cell from above the guard statement where you declared phoneCell it throws the error because phoneCell is not returned.

i had the same problem coming from NSMutableAttributedString
because internally it led to a [collectionView layoutSubviews] which caused the error.
the only -hacky- solution is to wrap whatever causing the call to NSMutableAttributedString in DispatchQueue.main.async {}

Can you schare an example pls? Have the same issue but cant fix It.

Are you using dequeueReusableCell outside of cellForItemAt for cell sizing, for instance?
I resolved this by replacing calls of dequeueReusableCell outside of cellForItemAt by instantiating cells directly.
Open the comments in this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/756645?answerId=790296022#790296022

existing (crashed)
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CallDetailsButtonViewCell.toString(), for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    if buttonInfo.type == .release {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CallDetailsReleaseButtonViewCell.toString(), for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    }

after fixing
        var cell =
    if buttonInfo.type == .release {
        collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CallDetailsReleaseButtonViewCell.toString(), for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    } else {
        collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CallDetailsButtonViewCell.toString(), for: indexPath as IndexPath)
    }

mostly this is related to one of the debugger suggestions point.

.. When the collection view's data source is asked to provide a view for a given index path,
ensure that a single view is dequeued and returned to the collection view.


my case to comment code it will working fine. my code just temporary comment after working fine all code
just fix
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

method commit after run properly.

I solved the problem by getting rid of the repeated calls to dequeueReusableCell method.
Once in the cellFotItemAt and second time in the sizeForItemAt to get back the exact cell size.
In my case:
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource

extension YourCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: YourCellType = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
        let item = viewModel?.items[indexPath.row]
        cell.configure(with: item)
        return cell
    }
}

// MARK: - UIColectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension YourCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> CGSize {
        let cell: YourCellType = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
        let viewModel = viewModel?.items[indexPath.item]
        return cell.size(for: viewModel)
    }
}

I changed the sizeForItemAt function as shown below and the problem disappeared:
// MARK: - UIColectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

extension YourCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> CGSize {
        // Creating a temporary cell to calculate the size
        let cell = YourCellType(frame: .zero)
        let viewModel = viewModel?.items[indexPath.item]
        // returns the calculated size for the current model
        return cell.size(for: viewModel) 
    }
}

If you use fixed-size cells, you can use boundingSize instead of sizeForItemAt:
extension YourCell: CollectionViewCellSelfSizeProvider {
    static func size(boundingSize: CGSize, viewModel: CellViewModel) -> CGSize {
        Layout.cellSize
    }
}


It looks like Apple is finally enforcing that we need to use collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) to only return the desired cell and do nothing else.
// only return your desired cell -- do nothing else!!
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
}

If you need to further the cell (which you likely do), there is a separate method that is more appropriate for this called collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:).
/// example cell configuration code.
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let card = cell as? CardProtocol else {
        return
    }

    let cardModel = cardModel(for: indexPath)
    card.configure(with: cardModel)
}

Looking at the stack trace, my guess is that configuring the cell within collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) now has some side effect (starting in iOS18) that has a chance to call dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: more than once under the hood.
It doesn't always happen, especially with simple cells. I've personally experienced this crash issue when configuring the cell within collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:) in the following, more complex situations:

cell has a label that uses an attributed string
cell has an image view fetches an image from the server

Once I moved the cell configuration-related code to collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:), the issue seems to have disappeared.

I fixed it by removeing one of dequeueReusableXXX code.
before
if let cell = dequeueReusableXXX as? Cell1 { } else if let cell = dequeueReuableXXX as? Cell2 { }
after
if data is Cell1.Type, let cell = dequeueReusableXXX as? Cell1 { } else if data is Cell2.Type, let cell = dequeueReuableXXX as? Cell2 { }
collectionview only allows you to execute dequeueReusableXXX once
